# Default Values are persisting onSubmit - react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to not persist the values that are defaulting on my form because my backend cannot deal with that when the objects are empty, Is there some way to do that on the onSubmit to remove ( react hook form )?

```
const [defaultValues] = useState<FormValues>({
    title: '',
    people: {
      label: '',
      value: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        role: '',
        pictureUrl: '',
      },
    },
 ....
}
 ......
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off">
```

I'm using a workaround but it's a huge function haha

```
function deepClean(data: any): any {
  if (typeof data !== 'object' || data === null) {
    // Return data if not an object or null
    return data;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    // Recursively clean array elements
    return data
      .map(deepClean)
      .filter(item => item !== null && item !== '' && !(typeof item === 'object' && Object.keys(item).length === 0));
  }

  // Recursively clean object properties
  const cleanedObj = Object.entries(data)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      const cleanedValue = deepClean(value);
      if (cleanedValue !== null && cleanedValue !== '' && !(typeof cleanedValue === 'object' && Object.keys(cleanedValue).length === 0)) {
        acc[key] = cleanedValue;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {} as any);

  return cleanedObj;
}
```

That's why I want help to know if there's some way on default by the react hook form ( I checked the DOCS but is only the basic approach for the submit)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: Hi @Axnyff no worries, the solution seems good with the function that I created ( I did after created the post here), but anyway if somebody know a better that to do it when there's defaultValeus on the form will be lovely :)